# My simple physics system makes object shake instead of standing still

Tags: lua, game-physics, roblox, physics-engine, luau

I am currently trying to make a system (for roblox) that is basically just a Vector3 that has physics and collision, it doesn't have volume it's literally just a vector position in 3d space. I've made a small amount of progress but I don't really know what the best way of going at making this is.

This is what it looks like when I run the simulation and let the coins fall. (Ignore the static coin in the center)
[Picture of visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0npia.png)

These coins are just a sprite that I put on top of the Position of the orb. So the position of the coin is at the very bottom of the coin (at the floor).

I made a visualization too, so every arrow you see is a different raycast that checks for interference/collision.

The problem:

If you watch this little clip, you can see the problem instantly. My coin is shaking when it is in a place like this. I think this has to do with the bounce code I made.
https://gyazo.com/38b1903b33d8f7e4ab5b477acdd5f1d2

How would I make it so that my coin only bounces a couple of times and then stops, while still behaving like it should iykwim.

This is my current code in the step function (called every frame).

```lua
if (self.Anchored) then return end
    
self.LastPosition = self.Position
    
self.Velocity += self.Gravity * DT
self.Position += self.Velocity * DT

local Result: RaycastResult? = self:_raycast(self.LastPosition, self.Position)
if (Result) then
    self.Position = Result.Position
    self.Velocity = ReflectNormal(Direction, Result.Normal) * (self.Velocity.Magnitude * self.BounceMultiplier)
end
```

I expect my coin to not start shaking when it gets "stuck" like that. It should only move when it has too.

Comment: I think you have to do an extra check of your spawning Coins. This kind of shaking happens when an Object spawn inside another Object. Or if it is spawning at exact Position of another Object Position.